# What does the String array argument do in Java's main function?

Tags: java, string, program-entry-point

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("What that String do in main function argument");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm disappointed in the downvotes here.  This is a straightforward question that just needed a bit of editing.  I couldn't find a duplicate question.  Nobody's voted to close or explained their downvote.  +1 to compensate.  I'd like to welcome Ravi to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanx Erick Robertson :)

Comment: Downvotes might have been harsh but the post demonstrates a lack of research on the part of the OP. https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=java+main+method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provides the command line arguments to the code.

Here is some reference: [Hello World Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html)

Comment: The command line argument docs are far more useful than the Hello World Tutorial (which doesn't even use the command line, and only mentions the argument in passing): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: public class ravi {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
 for(int i = 0 ; i<args.length;i++){
 System.out.println(args[i]);
 }
    }
}  now clear :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are running it on the command line you can pass in arguments.

`java myprogram a b c d "e f g"`

Will produce `args = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e f g"]`

Answer (score 0):

These refer to the command line arguments: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html